# I have an error when loading lock screen theme when starting Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lock-screen, qt

When I select a theme on Kubuntu, it's apply the theme but after restarting Kubuntu and loading the lock this error appear:

[image: Image of my lock screen]

I already tried the other themes, but it still didn't work even after I installed the QT quick version 5

Comment: Why'd you reject the edit?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yeah the question could have been written better

Comment: (i) what distribution are you on (ii) what theme are you trying to install (iii) how did you install QtQuick?